# Why my download speed is high but my speed test is slow ?! is this ISP trick?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router

I have a "12mb" Internet connection and my download speed with IDM is "1780kB/s" and it's Ok. But speedtest.net tells me "your internet speed is not 12mb actually it's 3.85mb"

How does it just possible? I just call my ISP support and tell them this issue and they said "Speedtest.net is not our source!!" What does it mean? What is source ?

I just want to know why my speed test is very different with my Download speed? I think my speed is fake and shaky, please guide me :)

[image]

[image]

Comment: What exactly is your question?  The server you are downloading the actual file is slower, then the servers, from speedtest.net which explains the speed difference.

Comment: Untrue, the download is 1.6 MBps and the speed test is only 3.85 Mbps (0.48 MBps).

Comment: so why it just become 12mb now ? if the servers in speedtest is slow ?

i just want to know why when my speed test is 3.85mb, my download speed is still  "1780kB/s" ?! how it can be possible ?

Can someone explain this problem ? why when my test speed is 3mb, i can download with 12mb in any server and sites ?!
 
http://www.speedtest.net/result/4517518513.png

common guys i just ask question , it must have rational reason in ICT.

Comment: As long as the real wold behaviour is better than the theoretical test you don't have to worry though...

Comment: Was the link in use while you were performing the speed test?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried other speedtest.net server to see if that gives the same result? It also might vary by time of day.

The reason for this behaviour is the way the internet is built. Basicly every ISP is its own big network and you usually get very fast speeds and latencies as long as you stay inside the network of your ISP. The problems now start if you need to get to a server that has a different ISP than you. That means you have to cross a border in the internet and like in real life this can become tricky.

Crossing this border means that both ISPs have to setup a shared link that has a given bandwidth. The more the better of course. The problem is that these links can be expensive and the ISP is not getting usually not any money from this link. So some ISPs are quite reluctant to invest in these links and just build a token interconnect that are way to small for the traffic needed.

This leads to the behaviours you see, especialy if one of the ISPs on this link is quite popular. You than have a lot of people trying to use a link that is at capacity and that leads to slow downs for everyone. You can imagine it like a bridge during commuting hours that is too small for the traffic. Like a traffic jam on the internet :)

Comment: I test my speed with my ISP server, and it's still show me less than "3mb".


(12:30 PM)-
http://i.stack.imgur.com/IYPpW.png

(11:25 AM)-
http://i.stack.imgur.com/QIpyp.png

Comment: Look at this two pic i just test with my ISP server, in 12hours.
(12:30 PM)-
http://i.stack.imgur.com/IYPpW.png
(11:25 AM)-
http://i.stack.imgur.com/QIpyp.png
My DLspeed is static but my speedtest is dynamic.

Comment: And if your opinion about Local network is true, so i shouldn't have high speed download in external link outside my ISP, but i can download any link with 12mb.
And i just test my speed with my ISP servers too.

Comment: Try another server for speedtest, even if it appears farther away. From the pictures you showed it is most likely an issue that the server used for speedtesting is simply overloaded.